# How can I pass on information using in href?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, button, href

I'm using Session to pass on the object of the current user to the different aspx pages.
I have a home page, in which there are not any buttons, I'm only using href.
Is there a way to pass on the user info to the other pages with href? I know it can be done with somthing like: `href="page.aspx?userId=3"`, but I have the userId only on the code behing in c#, and I couldn't figure out how to get it, and also don't know how to know if the user moved to the page with Session or from the home page.

Comment: I assume this is WebForms?  Additionally... If the value is already known server-side and is kept in session state, why does it need to be included in that URL?

Comment: When I try to just get the Session the user object is null

Comment: Well, if session is null, then you not set session to the user id then, right??? I mean, once session is set, then you should be fine, and any and all pages can get the user id. On the other hand, you can and should be able to get the user id from the security provider you using for the logon, right? I think as a general rule, such PK database ID for the user should NEVER be exposed to the client side web page anyway. If you have that value in session, then code behind can freely use that ID, and I see little, if in not fact ZERO reasons to expose that id to client side code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like WebForms.  If so, the page markup is technically an inheriting object of the page code-behind and would have access to any `protected` members of that class.  For example, you can create a property in the code-behind:

```
protected UserId { get; set; }
```

And set that value anywhere you like in the code-behind.  When rendering the markup, that property can be accessed directly:

```
href="page.aspx?userId=<%= UserId %>"
```